# Parameter estimation for epidemic models

Tags: matlab, parameters, estimation

I have an epidemic model:

```
function ypsirid = ypsirid(t,y)
global q m b r
ypsirid(1) = q - m*y(1) - b*y(1)*y(2);
ypsirid(2) = (b*y(1)*y(2)) - (m+r)*y(2);
ypsirid(3) = (r*y(2)) - m*y(3);
ypsirid = ypsirid(:)
```

Can anyone kindly suggest the easiest possible method to carry out parameter estimation using matlab. Thanks!

Comment: I am guessing q m b r are your parameters. Do you have any sample data to which you would like to fit your model to ? fminsearch is a good starting point for this. If data is unavailable then you have to consider a cost function as a simple one based on RMSE cannot be used.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Sorry to provide insufficient info. Yes, q m b and r are the parameters out of which q and m are known. i need to estimate b and r. The major issue is the unavailability of data. I have managed to solve the model and simulate using assumed parameter values. But, I need to get estimated values now. Pls do help me with that!

Comment: Assuming this is an un-bounded Ill posed problem, one of the things you can do is to start by decreasing your search space dimensions from 4 to 2. (maybe simplify the model or fix 2 of the params. at 0 ) Then plot the solution space in 3D, f(t,y) where t=somevalue and y=somevalue. Plot qmb then repeat and plot mbr etc. Look up global/local gradient/free optimisation to examine the solution space with some upper and lower bounds for the parameters.

Comment: Optimisation methods (fmincon, fminsearch, opt. toolbox) can be used here to investigate the nature of the model with some initial starting conditions and parameter tweaking. Sorry for the late answer, the scope of the question is quite broad.